# The server on localhost doesnt seen to accept connection

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, server, localhost

```
//serv.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    FILE *log;
    int port_no;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    struct hostent* server;    int port_flag=0;
    int c;
    while(1)
    {
        static struct option long_options[]=
        {
            {"port",required_argument,0,'p'},
            {"log",required_argument,0,'l'},
        };
        c= getopt_long(argc,argv,"p:l",long_options,NULL);
        if(c==-1)
            break;
        switch(c)
        {
            case 'l':
                if(optarg)
                {
                    if(optarg[0]!='-')
                    {
                        log= fopen(optarg,"w");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fprintf(stderr,"log requires argument\n");
                    }

                }
                break;
            case 'p':
                if(optarg)
                {
                    if(optarg[0]!='-')
                    {
                        port_no= atoi(optarg);
                        port_flag=1;
                    }
                    else{
                        printf("Usage --port=PORT_NUMBER\n");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Usage --port=PORT_NUMBER\n");
                }
                break;
            case '?':
                write(STDOUT_FILENO,"\r",1);
                exit(1);
                break;
            default:
                break;

        }

    }

int opt = 0, port_num, client_len;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;
    socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(socket_fd < 0) { perror("Error opening socket"); exit(1); }
    memset((char*) &server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(port_num);
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    if(bind(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Error binding socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    listen(socket_fd,5);
    client_len=sizeof(client_addr);
    newsocket_fd=accept(socket_fd,(struct sockaddr *)&client_addr,&client_len);
    printf("accepting");
    if(newsocket_fd<0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"error on accept");

    }
    char buffer[256];
    memset(buffer,0,256);
    int n=read(newsocket_fd,buffer,255);
    if(n<0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error reading from socket");

    }
    printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);
    n=write(newsocket_fd,"I got your message",18);
}
```

client.c

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    FILE *log;
    int port_no;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    struct hostent* server;    int port_flag=0;
    int c;
    while(1)
    {
        static struct option long_options[]=
        {
            {"port",required_argument,0,'p'},
            {"log",required_argument,0,'l'},
        };
        c= getopt_long(argc,argv,"p:l",long_options,NULL);
        if(c==-1)
            break;
        switch(c)
        {
            case 'l':
                if(optarg)
                {
                    if(optarg[0]!='-')
                    {
                        log= fopen(optarg,"w");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fprintf(stderr,"log requires argument\n");
                    }

                }
                break;
            case 'p':
                if(optarg)
                {
                    if(optarg[0]!='-')
                    {
                        port_no= atoi(optarg);
                        port_flag=1;
                    }
                    else{
                        printf("Usage --port=PORT_NUMBER\n");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Usage --port=PORT_NUMBER\n");
                }
                break;
            case '?':
                write(STDOUT_FILENO,"\r",1);
                exit(1);
                break;
            default:
                break;

        }

    }
    char buffer[256];
            socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
            if(socket_fd < 0) { perror("Error opening socket"); exit(0); }
            server = gethostbyname("localhost");
            if(server == NULL) { fprintf(stderr, "Cannot find host"); exit(0); }
            //Initialize the server address to zero and then correctly assign it
            memset((char*) &server_addr,0, sizeof(server_addr));
            server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
            memcpy((char *) &server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
                   (char*) server->h_addr,
                   server->h_length);
            server_addr.sin_port = htons(port_no);


if(connect(socket_fd,(struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0) { perror("Error connecting"); exit(0); }
        printf("Please enter the message");
        memset(buffer,0,256);
        fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
        int n=write(socket_fd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
        if(n<0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"error writing to socket");
        }
        memset(buffer,0,256);
        n=read(socket_fd,buffer,255);
        if(n<0)
        {
            printf("Error reading");
        }
        printf("%s\n",buffer);}
```

}

I don't know why but the server doesn't seem to accept the socket
connection from client. I have tried port numbers more than 1024. Just
doesn't work. port number is user entered. Is there a port_no only for which it will work?

Comment: What error do you get, and from where?

Comment: No error just hangs keeps waiting to connect

Comment: Assuming the above is the ACTUAL code you used in your test, port_num in serv.c hasn't been initialized... Can we assume you started "serv" first, and then "client"... which "hung"...???

Comment: Yes spot on  ! Ther serv.c and client.c both take port number as argument in --port= option in getopt long

Comment: perhaps your "getopt" handling is the problem... we have no idea because you didn't include that code... you should provide MCVE [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)     Additional suggestion: add a newline to your "printf()" statements, otherwise they may not appear until your program exits.

Comment: You can simply catch error in server client application by checking return values of send() connect() write() read() or etc.. functions.  see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xns/syssocket.h.html

Comment: for write () see: http://gd.tuwien.ac.at/languages/c/programming-bbrown/c_075.htm

Comment: I am checking as u can see but it doesnt send anything

Comment: Do you see your server listening on given port in output of netstat command?

Comment: Please provide a minimal, *runnable* demonstration of the problem.

Comment: ok guys i have put up full code with getopt hope you cn help me now

Answer (score 1):

The "full code" you posted clearly isn't full, since it won't compile (hint: client.c doesn't include a single header file). With trivial fixes made, an important clue comes from compiling with warnings enabled:

```
$ gcc -g serv.c -o serv -Wall -Wextra
serv.c: In function 'main':
serv.c:94:71: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 3 of 'accept' differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
     int newsocket_fd=accept(socket_fd,(struct sockaddr *)&client_addr,&client_len);
                                                                       ^
In file included from serv.c:7:0:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/socket.h:243:12: note: expected 'socklen_t * __restrict__' but argument is of type 'int *'
 extern int accept (int __fd, __SOCKADDR_ARG __addr,
            ^
serv.c:79:5: warning: unused variable 'opt' [-Wunused-variable]
 int opt = 0, port_num, client_len;
     ^
serv.c:23:36: warning: variable 'port_flag' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     struct hostent* server;    int port_flag=0;
                                    ^
serv.c:23:21: warning: unused variable 'server' [-Wunused-variable]
     struct hostent* server;    int port_flag=0;
                     ^
serv.c:21:9: warning: variable 'port_no' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     int port_no;
         ^
serv.c:20:11: warning: variable 'log' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     FILE *log;
           ^
serv.c:111:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
serv.c:85:28: warning: 'port_num' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
     server_addr.sin_port = htons(port_num);
```

Look at that last warning - "port_num" uninitialised? Look further up:  "port_no" initialised but not used? So that argument processing is in vain and you're listening on an arbitrary port - the suggestion of checking "netstat -l -p" by @Pras would have shown this too.

As a debugging strategy it's worth compiling with pedantic warnings (and try with a more diagnostic compiler like clang) to look for clues. As a common development strategy reduce the time spent debugging by always enabling warnings and fixing them before even running the code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are asking about the server here is what I noticed.

Both "port_no" and "port_num" declared, the user input it assigned to "port_no" but you are using "port_num" when calling htons().

You have a redeclaration of ‘server_addr’ after your switch case, and are also missing newsocket_fd

```
$gcc -o server server.c 
server.c: In function ‘main’:
server.c:80:24: error: redeclaration of ‘server_addr’ with no linkage
     struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~
server.c:22:24: note: previous declaration of ‘server_addr’ was here
     struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~
server.c:81:5: error: ‘socket_fd’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     ^~~~~~~~~
server.c:81:5: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
server.c:94:5: error: ‘newsocket_fd’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     newsocket_fd=accept(socket_fd,(struct sockaddr *)&client_addr,&client_len);
```

Either way I removed the switch case and manually assigned the port number to get it running, you need to check your inputs and clean up a few more errors but here is a working example of your code with comments about the changes.

I used netcat as a client to test the connection.

```
$ netcat 127.0.0.1 5555
test message
I got your message
```

The output code was not changed from what you provided, this is what it will display. use "\n" for a newline.

```
$gcc -o server server.c 
example@pc:~$./server
acceptingHere is the message: test message
```

Here is the modified code:

```
//serv.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    FILE *log;
    // Added socket_fd and newsocket_fd
    int socket_fd, newsocket_fd;
    // use uint16_t for port number    
    uint16_t port_no;
    //Removed struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    struct hostent* server;    int port_flag=0;
    int c;

    port_no = 5555;
    /* removed switch to show server does function
    while(1)
    {
        static struct option long_options[]=
        {
            {"port",required_argument,0,'p'},
            {"log",required_argument,0,'l'},
        };
        c= getopt_long(argc,argv,"p:l",long_options,NULL);
        if(c==-1)
            break;
        switch(c)
        {
            case 'l':
                if(optarg)
                {
                    if(optarg[0]!='-')
                    {
                        log= fopen(optarg,"w");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fprintf(stderr,"log requires argument\n");
                    }

                }
                break;
            case 'p':
                if(optarg)
                {
                    if(optarg[0]!='-')
                    {
                        port_no= atoi(optarg);
                        port_flag=1;
                    }
                    else{
                        printf("Usage --port=PORT_NUMBER\n");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Usage --port=PORT_NUMBER\n");
                }
                break;
            case '?':
                write(STDOUT_FILENO,"\r",1);
                exit(1);
                break;
            default:
                break;

        }

    }
    */

    // Removed port_num
    int opt = 0, client_len;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;
    socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(socket_fd < 0) { perror("Error opening socket"); exit(1); }
    memset((char*) &server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    // using port_no in htons
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(port_no);
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    if(bind(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Error binding socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    listen(socket_fd,5);
    client_len=sizeof(client_addr);
    newsocket_fd=accept(socket_fd,(struct sockaddr *)&client_addr,&client_len);
    printf("accepting");
    if(newsocket_fd<0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"error on accept");

    }
    char buffer[256];
    memset(buffer,0,256);
    int n=read(newsocket_fd,buffer,255);
    if(n<0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error reading from socket");

    }
    printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);
    n=write(newsocket_fd,"I got your message",18);
}
```